# Automatically follow all answers to my questions

Tags: discussion, follow-posts

In Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange, is there a setting I can enable to automatically follow all answers to questions that I post?

Reason: 99% of the answers to my questions are very good. If answerers make a change to their answer, I want to know about it, even if it's a just a minor change. Sure, I can manually follow answers. But it's hard to remember to hit follow every time an answer comes in.

---

With that said, answerers often make several edits to their answers shortly after posting. So, admittedly, that could result in a lot of notifications. I can't recall, but maybe the *follow notifications* get grouped together as a single notification per answer, reducing the potential number of notifications.

And if there are answers I don't want to follow, I could manually unfollow them if I want to. But that's pretty rare.

So I'm curious, does that functionality exist?